# How to simply my code?

Tags: vb.net

i have a little problem.i'm beginner in visual basic.i want to do a project with this visual studio.this my example project.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    MaskedTextBox3.Text = MaskedTextBox1.Text \ MaskedTextBox2.Text & "A"
    MaskedTextBox4.Text = MaskedTextBox2.Text & "Ω"
```

-for example,i want write 5 / 2 and it turn to 2 not 2.5 .what code must i add at this project?please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
MaskedTextBox3.Text = cint(MaskedTextBox1.Text \ MaskedTextBox2.Text).toString & "A"
```

Basically convert the 2.5 to an Integer.

Comment: But converting to interger rounds always down. The user didnt mention the required rounding rule. I would recommend the msdn round page too.

Comment: I was going with this `and it turn to 2 not 2.5`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Math.Round method. This will give you control over whether you want to round toward or away from zero.

[Math.Round method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use [this function](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_cdbl.asp):

```
If IsNumeric(txtFirst.Text) And IsNumeric(txtSecond.Text) Then
  txtSum.Text = CStr(CDbl(txtFirst.Text) + CDbl(txtSecond.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help your programming if you do things in small steps for each part. It may be more lines, but it can be more descriptive, and thus simpler to understand if you come back to the code in the future.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim voltage As Double = CDbl(MaskedTextBox1.Text)
    Dim resistance As Double = CDbl(MaskedTextBox2.Text)
    MaskedTextBox3.Text = Math.Floor(voltage / resistance).ToString() & "A"
    MaskedTextBox4.Text = MaskedTextBox2.Text & "Ω"
```

Please notice that I used CDbl to convert the *text* into a *number*, in this case the numbers are of type Double, and that I used .ToString() to convert the number resulting from the calculation into a String (text).

You can get Visual Studio to point out where types of variables do not match up (string to string, number to number) in VB by using [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zcd4xwzs.aspx).